# How to show checked radio button in edit view in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, radio-button

in  my edit view i can retain value of the fields but the radio button.
like wen i select the row from grid and click edit it gives me previously saved value for all othr field bt not for radio buttons

how can i set those value
lik if the saved data contain value of gender as F then

```
if(gender='f')
 {
    <input type="radio" name="forwhom" value="f" checked="checked"></input>
 }
else
  <input type="radio" name="forwhom" value="m" checked="checked"></input>
```

i'm showing my data using 2 partial views as follows

do i have to write any ajax for it??
 please help
regards!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Razor](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx) in this case:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "radioValue", new { @checked = true })
```

More about it here:

[How to set Html.RadioButtonFor as selected by default in Asp.net MVC3](http://dotnetech.wordpress.com/2011/03/20/how-to-set-one-html-radiobuttonfor-as-selected-by-default-in-asp-net-mvc3/)

Comment: thanx for replying Bt since i'm using the same view for edit and create can u suggest sumthing which i can use in html input tags

Answer (score -1):

or try this.

```
if(gender = 'f')
 {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "radioValue", new { @checked = "true"})
 }
else 
 {
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Gender, "radioValue", new {@checked = "true"})      
 }
```

hope to help you out.. thanks.